# DownloadManager returned Uri is unusable in Android 13

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager, android-13

I am trying to download a file into the external public directory but the Uri returned by `downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(requestId)` isn't usable. I'm unable to launch an `ACTION_OPEN` intent with it, even though this same process works for Android 10.

I suspect this has something to do with missing updated permissions on Android 13, but there are no errors logged in logcat.

I am able to get it working as expected by using `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir` to store the file inside the private applications directory and using a `ContentResolver` to copy it into the phones external media storage, but that is a lot of code and very verbose. Using `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` from `DownloadManager` is a lot cleaner and concise.

This is how I am creating and enqueuing my request

```kotlin
    val request = DownloadManager
            .Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrl))
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES,
                "${UUID.randomUUID()}.mp4"
            )
            .setMimeType("video/mp4")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .setTitle("Saving...")
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)

         
   requestId = downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

And this is how I am listening for download completion and attempting to use the Uri.

```kotlin
    private val downloadBroadCastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val requestId = intent?.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1) ?: -1

            val query = DownloadManager.Query()
            query.setFilterById(requestId)

            val cursor = downloadManager.query(query)

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)

                when (cursor.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL -> {
                        LOG.info("onReceive: Video download completed!")

                        val uri = downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(requestId)

                        context.startActivity(
                            Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri).apply {
                                setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4")
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
           }   
        }
```

Comment: Think you have to add a READ permission flag to the view intent.

Comment: @blackapps Do you mind sharing where that READ flag should go.

Comment: Every example of an intent for ACTION_VIEW uses one.